# Error "filterlanguage: Invalid value specified: 1." when trying to create sfdx package version

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, package, custom-reports, unlocked-package

I have the task of creating a sfdx package that includes various reports and dashboards.
Sadly when I tried to create the package version I got this error for a lot of my reports:

"filterlanguage: Invalid value specified: 1.,"

I Know that this Error is somehow related to the Filter Language and can be avoided when enabling the translation workbench prior to the deployment of the package.

Is there a way to get rid of this error in the package creation or somehow include the workbench activation in the package?

Thanks a lot for replies.

Best Regards,
Felix

Comment: Can you post your config file code. As per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50 it's possible to have translation as a part of unlocked package

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply,
Do you mean the code in the config folder for the project-scratch-def.json?
It would be:

`{
    "orgName": "Reports and Dashboards Scratch Org",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "language": "en_US",
    "features": ["PersonAccounts", "MarketingUser"]
    } `


(Sorry I am new to the package creation)

Comment: Or do you mean the individual code in each report I try to package? Because I just noticed there is a part that says `<language>en_US</language>` for the filters. Can I just remove that?

Comment: yes the orgname you mentioned that one. Are you using that one while creation of package? you can check the command you might be using - `sfdx force:package:version:create --package <PackageName> --key <password> -f <configurationFilePath>`

Comment: Yes it is the one I am using. Do I just remove the Language value there?

Answer (score 0):

Need to include translation workbench in the scratch org definition

```
"settings": {
    "languageSettings": {
        "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
    }
}
```